# .htaccess Rewriting specifics

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

These htaccess rules are driving me nuts, I've tried loads of examples and generators and got knowhere...

my htaccess looks like the following

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^location/([^/]*)\.html$ /location.php?location=$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /search.php?searching=yes&s=$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm trying to get

```
http://www.domain.com       
to http://domain.com (works)

http://domain.com/index.php 
to http://domain.com (works)
```

Rewrite all php extensions to html i.e

```
http://domain.com/location.php 
to http://domain.con/location.html (doesnt work)

http://domain.com/about.php    
to http://domain.con/about.html (doesnt work)

http://domain.com/support.php  
to http://domain.com/support.html (doesnt work)
```

Rewrite the below variables

```
http://domain.com/location.php?location=bedfordshire 
to http://domain.com/location/bedfordshire.html (doesnt work)

http://domain.com/search.php?searching=yes&s=langster&pmin=&daf=&search=&pmax=&dab= 
to http://domain.com/langster.html (doesnt work)
```

Some pages like index.php, location.php and search.php have page and other variables but I don't really want to go into that can of worms yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/location\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^location=(.+)$
RewriteRule .* /location/%1.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*&s=([^&]+)
RewriteRule .* /%1.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

...and to process the redirected requests and pass them back to PHP as arguments, use following rules:

```
RewriteRule ^location/(.+)\.html$ /location.php?noloop=1&location=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ /search.php?s=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi these work (thanks)... but require the actual files to be there, is there not a way to do it virtally?

Comment: @user1639745 updated the answer with a new section. Have a look

Comment: Thats a loop without an end... it just keeps on redirecting round in a circle :)

Comment: @user1639745 true, it's a bit tricky. There was missing some condifions - see updated answer, works on my testing setup